# python pygame android app crashes after running apk on mobile device

Tags: python, android, pygame, buildozer

I developed a game utilizing python pygame framework which works well while testing using pycharm in desktop PC. For converting to an android app, Ubuntu 19.10 OS running on Oracle VM VirtualBox was used. APK file was obtained by running command `buildozer android debug`. But on running the command `buildozer android deploy run logcat > log.txt`, the following error message gets recorded in the log.txt file and app crashes.

> File "/home/nirmal/Desktop/App/.buildozer/android/app/main.py " line 69 in module.
> pygame.error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: imagefile.png
> Python for android ended

The line 69 in main.py corresponding to the error:

```
IMG = pygame.image.load('imagefile.png')
```

The file location `/home/nirmal/Desktop/App/.buildozer/android/app/` was checked and the availability of the file `imagefile.png` is confirmed.
Only pygame is used in the code. Kivy is not used. The code is written in python3.

Here is my *buildozer.spec* file

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Game Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = gameapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.nirmal

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all 
the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude 
anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not 
exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,pygame

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, 
#sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or 
# not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android 
# toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the 
# following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, 
# yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, 
# maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your 
# app will support,         it should usually match 
# android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public 
# storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be 
# automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be 
# automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically 
# downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or 
# save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your 
# package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set 
# to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first 
# running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based 
# app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
# android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that 
# pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since 
# extra jars can     slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for 
# example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project 
# (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only 
# with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only 
# with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain 
#java libraries     using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' 
# option see 
# https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8- 
# support for further     information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8",     
# "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for 
# some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url     
# 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-    dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-    
# INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META- 
# INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 
# png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %
# (source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in 
# <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into 
# libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set 
# this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value 
# format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in 
# the project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to 
# AndroidManifest.xml     using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, 
# arm64-v8a, x86,     x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream 
#(kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it 
# will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should 
# look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a 
# argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug 
#version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios 
# list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> 
# <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the 
# release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with 
#command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = 
#False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative 
#to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    ------------------------------------------------------- 
# ----------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = 
# license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    ------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your 
application     without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add    
# (demo)  in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD 
content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: if you get `FileNotFoundException` then use full path to image. Device may run code from different folder then you expect (Current Working Directory - see `os.getcwd()`) and then it searchs images in different folder then you expect - and then you have to add folder to filename to work with full path. There are even examples how to find folder with code using something like `APP_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`  and later use `os.path(APP_FOLDER, imagefile.png')`. You can often see this problem when people try to convert Python to `.exe` using `pyinstaller`

Comment: @furas, the image files were moved to the 'images' folder and the code edited:                                                            current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)                                                                                   image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images')                                                                        IMG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'imagefile.png'))                                     But the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: images/imagefile.png" is coming.

Comment: You still have only relative path and it can't find it. I put `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` only as idea what to search in Google because real solution uses also `os.path.abspath()` (or something similar) to create absolute path. So use Google to find it in stackoverflow or on PyInstaller's page.

Answer (score 0):

@furas, thank you very much. The `os.getcwd()` did the trick. I was under the wrong impression that `os.path.dirname(__file__)` produces an absolute path but in fact it outputs only relative path (empty string in this case). The code is edited as follows:-
`current_path = os.getcwd() image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images') IMG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'imagefile.png'))`.
Similar problem existed at two more places in the code and the same technique is used there too.
The issue of

> pygame.error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

is resolved with that. Now the android app (*apk* file) is running smoothly in the mobile phone.